# Insert entry into SQLite3 table in a conditional C++ loop statement

Tags: c++, sqlite, serial-port

I am using SQLite3 header files in my C++ program and trying to create a table and insert data onto it, it works fine on a regular input.

It shows error when I use it in a C++ loop with changing variables.

I am using the database to insert my reading from RS-232.

Here is my code:

```
                sqlite3 *db;
                char *zErrMsg = 0;
                int rc;
                char *sql;
                std::string sql_str;
                std::ostringstream temp;
                std::string command;

                /* Open database */
                rc = sqlite3_open("test_1.db", &db);
                if (rc){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    exit(0);
                }
                else{
                    fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
                }

                std::string str;
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << id_count; // stornig the primary id int values into a string 

                str = "INSERT INTO M_DATA (ID, DETAILS) VALUES(";
                str += oss.str(); //copying the int primary id
                str += ", '";

                std::string str_t1(szBuffer);  //Copying character aray to a string
                str += str_t1; //concatening the string

                str += "');";

                //printing what the database takes
                //output_file << std::endl << str << std::endl;

                char * writable = new char[str.size() + 1];
                std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable);
                writable[str.size()] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0

                sql = writable;

                output_file << std::endl << "## SQL COMMAND : " << sql << "#" << std::endl;

                // don't forget to free the string after finished using it
                delete[] writable;

                rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);


                if (rc != SQLITE_OK){
                    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                    output_file << std::endl << "** SQL ERROR : " << zErrMsg << "*" << std::endl;
                    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

                }
                else{
                    fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");

                }
                //  _sleep(3000);
                sqlite3_close(db);
```

My issue is I have a szBuffer which changes everytime, and I have to insert it as a new entry into the table.

Is there a way to increment the Primary Key and store my string into it?

The sz buffer at a single line will give data like: For Ex:

> szBuffer :  
>  ersion = 1  [SPI]: MinorVersion = 2  [SPI]: Real Time
>   = 1434260351  [SPI]: SR # = SBB-ST1000090

The SQL command in the string I pass is like this:

> SQL COMMAND : 
>   INSERT INTO M_DATA (ID, DETAILS) VALUES(9,
>   'ersion = 1  [SPI]: MinorVersion = 2 [SPI]: Real Time = 1434260351 
>   [SPI]: SR # = SBB-ST1000090');

The Error which I get is like:

> SQL ERROR : 
>   near "¸”_": syntax error

I am not sure if I am doing this right or wrong.
Can we use the insert statement in a loop? Am I passing the string the right way? (It looks correct to me when I print it out.)
But why do I get an error?

Is there any better way to enter my data?
I am very new to this so I tried search the internet, but no one is doing it the way I did it.
Please help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Does the `INSERT` command work if you execute it from an SQL script at the database? Apparently it doesn't like the `"` you'll need a `'` as delimiters for text IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, the command works if it is not in a loop. But I did not find the "  in the SQL command if you observe it. I am using a '

Comment: Well, the SQL engine clearly complains of a `"`. You should check if some `"` character might appear in any of the `INSERT` commands you issue (e.g. appearing in the Details text). You can use [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to do so.

Comment: Ok, but It is not the same always, some times it is     
    `near "À_": syntax error` 
It is not just " that it is uncomfortable with.
But when I print the string I am passing as the SQLcommand, it looks perfectly fine. @πάνταῥεῖ , Thank you very much for your responses.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Almost) never build a SQL statement via string concatenation. Use a prepared statement and bind the parameter values.

```
// Prepare the statement
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO M_DATA (ID, DETAILS) VALUES(?, ?);", -1, &stmt, nullptr);
// TODO: Handle when result != SQLITE_OK

while(/* whatever you wanted to loop on */)
{
  // Bind in the parameter values
  result = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, id_count);
  // TODO: Handle when result != SQLITE_OK
  result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, szBuffer, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
  // TODO: Handle when result != SQLITE_OK

  // Invoke the statement
  result = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  // TODO: Handle when result != SQLITE_OK

  // Reset the statement to allow binding variables on the next iteration
  result = sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}

// Release the statement
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: Then should I pass it into the executable statement like this?
`rc = sqlite3_exec(db, stmt /*instead of sql*/, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);` ?
But my `sql` is a char array.

Comment: No, the statement is executed by `sqlite3_step()`. Please read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html).

Comment: @Dark Falcon, thank you very much for your solution. I was doing it completely wrong before. The program runs fine now, without any error. Even if I include it in my C loop.

Comment: See [clear_bindings](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/clear_bindings.html): " Contrary to the intuition of many, sqlite3_reset() does not reset the bindings on a prepared statement. Use this routine to reset all host parameters to NULL. "